# How to update a record directly referenced in VF Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I'm using Custom Object and displaying the fields to be editable on the vf page. Can I update it directly on Controller class? My code is provided below:

Apex Class:

```
public class MyController{
     public Object items{get;set;}
     public void getValues(){
        items = [Select Id, Name, Data1 from Object where Id=:ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Id')];
     }
     public void updateValues(){
        //Do I need to query the object again???
        items = [Select Id, Name, Data1 from Object where Id=:ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Id')];
        update items;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VF must call getValues() on pageload or on any container you are using like DIV tag or table or anthing that contains textbox with binding expression like **{!items.Name}**

```
public class MyController{
 public Object items{get;set;}
 public string name{get;set;} 
 public void getValues(){
    items = [Select Id, Name, Data1 from Object where Id=:ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Id')];
    name=items.Name; // or you can have directly have {!items.Name}
 }
 public void updateValues(){
    //Do I need to query the object again???
    items.Name=name;
    update items;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm using {!items.name} directly in vf page.